# Calculating HMAC in Rust

Tags: rust, hmac

In Java I can do this to calculate HMAC:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

//.......
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("some algorithm");
hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec("some secret", "some algorithm"));
byte[] res = hmac.doFinal(("some str").getBytes());
```

How can I do the same thing in Rust?

Comment: There is nothing in the standard libraries for HMAC.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan, the question is not about HMAC in the standard libraries.

Comment: Oh, come on—I made a simple statement which is perfectly true! I made no comment about anything else, for or against.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`rust-crypto`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto) appears to [offer HMAC](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/hmac.rs). The correct way to use it is to [install Cargo](http://crates.io/), and add

```
[dependencies.rust-crypto]
git = "https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto"
```

to your Cargo.toml.

It looks like the correct API is to call [`Hmac::new`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/hmac.rs#L68) with your selected key & digest (anything that implements the `Digest` trait works, e.g. [`Sha256`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/sha2.rs#L670)), feed data via [`input`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/hmac.rs#L81) and the extract the result with [`result`](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/hmac.rs#L92) (these require importing [the `Mac` trait](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/mac.rs#L16).

I cannot find any online documentation, but running `cargo doc` in your codebase locally after adding the dependency will build the docs of `rust-crypto` into (IIRC) `./target/doc/rust-crypto`.

Comment: `with your selected key & digest` - digest is the name of an algorithm, for example SHA1, SHA512, DES, correct?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, yeah, basically. [See the tests at the end of the file for examples of use](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/bd9f097058131f89ca85fb3a8f02d47833449061/src/rust-crypto/hmac.rs#L163).

Comment: that lib doesn't compile, it says "error: macro undefined: 'panic!'". Since fixing it myself and creating a pull request can take long, what would you suggest me? I think I should fix it locally and use it as it were my library.

Comment: I would suggest fixing it yourself and submit a pull request, yes. You can then point to your own fork in the dependency, or [just override the dependency locally](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#overriding-dependencies).